# Kafka Streams - Relation between "Stream threads" vs "Tasks" running on 1 C4.XLarge Machine

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Topology which has 5 Processors & 1 Source. Source topic for this topology has 200 partitions. My understanding is 200 tasks get created to match # of partitions for input topic.

This Kafka Streams app is running on C4.XLarge & these 200 tasks run on single stream thread which means this streams thread should be using up all the CPU Cores (8) & memory.

I know Kafka streams parallelism/scalability is controlled by number of stream threads. I can increase the num.stream.threads to 10, but how would it improve the performance if all of them run on single EC2 instance ?. How would it differ from running all tasks on single stream thread which is on single EC2 instance ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 8 core machine, you might want to run 8 `StreamsThreads`.

> This Kafka Streams app is running on C4.XLarge & these 200 tasks run on single stream thread which means this streams thread should be using up all the CPU Cores (8) & memory.

This does not sound correct. A single thread cannot utilize multiple cores. While configuring a single `StreamThread` implies that some more other background threads are started (consumer heartbeat thread; producer sender thread), it would assume that you cannot fully utilize all 8 cores with this setting.

If 8 `StreamsThreads` do not fully utilize your 8 cores you might consider to configure 16 thread. However note, that all thread will share the same network and thus, if the network is the actually limiting factor, running more threads won't give you higher throughput (or higher CPU utilization). For this case, you need to scale out using multiple EC2 instances.

Given that you have 200 tasks, you could conceptually run up to 200 `StreamThreads` but you probably own't need 200 threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I dint account for the additional baggages that come along with Stream threads. What is still unclear for me is, its not like more stream threads is gonna spin up more tasks. When the # of tasks is actually capped at # of partitions, what value does more stream threads add ?. Also started going through this site ->  https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/kafka-streams-internals-StreamThread.html

Comment: If you start more `StreamThreads` than tasks you don't gain anything (if you don't have StandbyTask configured). The additional `StreamThreads` would just be idle as they won't get any tasks assigned.

Comment: Say, I have a single Topic with 10 Partitions and I have 2 separate instances powering to streams-app. And, on each Stream-app configuration, I have added NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG=5, then I have in total 10 tasks possible. AND each of these 10 threads would get each Partition to work upon !   Is this understanding correct @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: Alright Thanks Matthias. Just another query on this is:-   Say, I have a single Topic with 10 Partitions and I have 2 separate instances powering to streams-app. And, on each Stream-app configuration, I have added NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG=10, then I have in total 20 logical tasks possible. Is it possible that kafka architecture allocates all 10 partitions to 10 streaming-tasks belonging to 1 single instance AND then another 10 streaming-tasks on 2nd instance remains absolutely idle ?? @MatthiasJ. Sax

Comment: If you have 10 partitions you should get 10 tasks per sub-topology. The task assigner considers load balancing and should assign 50% of all tasks to each instance.

Comment: Alright Thanks Matthias. Grateful for your responses !